# got confused with 'this' in one form in js

Tags: javascript

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Example 5.3</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function calculate(form) {
      form.results.value = eval(form.entry.value);
}
function getExpression(form) {
      form.entry.blur();
      form.entry.value = prompt("Please enter a JavaScript mathematical expression","");
      calculate(form);
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD=POST>
Enter a JavaScript mathematical expression:
<INPUT TYPE=text NAME="entry" VALUE="" onFocus="getExpression(this.form);">
<BR>
The result of this expression is:
<INPUT TYPE=text NAME="results" VALUE="" onFocus="this.blur();">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Above code is from one js tutorial.

Question:

`onFocus="getExpression(this.form);"` , what does `this` represent here? I thought it is window object, if so, then can not explain this line: `onFocus="this.blur();"`,  or both `this` mean the input field, if so, how to userstand `this.form`(input.form)?
I got confused with `'this'` here, could anyone explain to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> onFocus="getExpression(this.form);" , what does this represent here?

`this` here is your input `<INPUT TYPE=text NAME="entry"/>`

> onFocus="this.blur();"

`this` here is your input `<INPUT TYPE=text NAME="results"/>`

Answer (score 2):

`this` means it refers to that particular form, and that particular element.

Example: **this** is the Shortest answer I ever posted (Refers to this question)

Answer (score 0):

The this keyword is a tricky one in the JS Environment I would recommend this article since it really helped me to understand it some time ago. [Understanding the this keyword](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword/).

In this case if the function is not being executed by call() or apply() which modifies the behaviour of the this keyword it should represent the caller of the function, in this case the input that the event was triggered from.

Hope this helps :)